# Grails.ExtJS.authenticate function?

Tags: grails, extjs

I have this task:

realize Grails application with ExtJS.

And one part of this task:

realize authenticate function.

for example on `main.gsp` page we have `Ext.grid.GridPanel()` and button "`New`" and "`Details`" in `tbar`.

user must insert his login and password on `login.gsp`
if his data is correct his redirect to `main.gsp`

if user role - "`admin`", user - can click "`New`" button and added new rows in table, if user role "`simply_user`" - the button - "`New`" - deactive and user can only look table and no more.

and now for me the biggest problem - how to implement different js code on one page, depending on whether a user opens this page.

Somebody can give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but I'd say :

- in any case, your JS must be able to know which rights/role the current has (i.e. to enable/disable the button)
- also, you should **make sure** that server side, user rights are verified ;)

What I do, most of the time, is sending rights to the ExtJs Apps on the form :

```
MyApp.Config = { "user" : { "name" : "john doe", "roles" : ["admin"], ... } };
```

I do this in PHP in the layout page loaded after login, via :

```
<?php
$cfg = array("user" => array("name" => $user->name, "roles" => $user->roles);
printf('<script>MyApp.Config = %s;</script>', json_encode($cfg));
```

In the JS app:

```
var isAdmin = MyApp.Config.user.roles.indexOf('admin')>=0);
var button = new Ext.Button({text:'New', disabled : !isAdmin});
```

I'm sure you can do it easily with groovy ;)

Of course you can also send config via an `Ext.lib.Ajax.request` if there is no page reload between sessions.